# How to work around a global variable that invokes some I/O operation?

Tags: python

Suppose I have a module `data_provider.py` that keeps some code responsible for connecting to external API. In order to establish a connection, an API token needs to be retrieved from the database.

```
API_TOKEN = get_token_from_database()

class DataProvider:
    def __init__(self):
        self.api_token = API_TOKEN

def make_query(self):
    '''make some request using self.api_token'''
```

Assuming the code needs to stay in such shape more or less (`API_TOKEN` being a global variable), what would be a good pattern for retrieving the `API_TOKEN` from the database?

Obiously now it is not ideal because the module cannot be imported without the database being turned on. Also, I would like to retrieve it only once, not per `DataProvider` creation.

Should I for example make `API_TOKEN` load lazily or turn it into a function?

Comment: Who and how often creates `DataProvider`?

Comment: token should be parameter  in the `__init__()` and this way the class is encapsulated and reusable, allowing to use different tokens in different instances. Alternatively to having token being global variable, it can be retrieved inside the `__init__()`. That is assuming you want to reuse the same token for as long as the instance is live/exists.

Comment: You should pass the token to the constructor of `DataProvider` (aka "dependency injection"). That way, you have complete control over when the token is generated. Also, you avoid global mutable state, which has a code smell anyways. Don't try to fix that cludge, do it properly! If you really have to, you can preserve API compatibility making it an optional constructor parameter even.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd probably go with a simple singleton pattern

```
class DataProvider:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__api_token = None

    def get_token(self):
       if self.__api_token is None:
            self.__api_token = .....
       return self.__api_token
```

You might want to make `get_token(self)` into a property `token` instead.  That's a matter of taste.

Comment: That is not an application of the Singleton Pattern, though similar. It's just an on-demand initialized member variable.

Comment: Some definitions of the "Singleton pattern" include initialization on demand.  That's what I have above.  The token is initialized the first time you call get_token()

Answer (score 1):

If you have one single `DataProvider` object in your application, you could simply remove the global variable and load the token in the `__init__` method:

```
class DataProvider:
    def __init__(self):
        self.api_token = get_token_from_database()
```

Another possible *lazy loading* would be to initialize the global token to `None` and then set it at first instanciation of a DataProvider object

```
API_TOKEN = None

class DataProvider:
    def __init__(self):
        global API_TOKEN

        if API_TOKEN is None:
            API_TOKEN = get_token_from_database()
        self.api_token = API_TOKEN
```

Error processing still omitted for brievety...